# Protractor : not able to find element in login page

Tags: protractor

I am novice user of protractor and trying to use it for angularjs application,
Config file snippet :

```
 exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['plugins/./test_spec.js'],

    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1240000
    }

};
```

Working test case (spec file):

```
describe('Login', function () {
    it('Login Page', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000/apps/admin/');
        element(by.model('ctrl.user.name'))
        element(by.model('ctrl.user.password'))
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

Failing test case (spec file):

```
describe('Login', function () {
    it('Login Page', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000/apps/admin/');
        element(by.model('ctrl.user.name')).sendKeys("test1");
        element(by.model('ctrl.user.password')).sendKeys("test1");
        element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

Trying to use sendKeys for login page is failing but without sendkeys test case passes, I am getting following error:

```
Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 60 seconds
    (Session info: chrome = 72.0.3626.109)
    (Driver info: chromedriver = 2.46.628402(536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1), platform = Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I suspect element not being found.
Please guide me through this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommended to add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,` to your `protractor.config` file due to this [thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969), if tells it shortly - better to don't use Control Flow. So how will look your config file:

```
 exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['plugins/./test_spec.js'],

    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    getPageTimeout: 30000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1240000
    },
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

};
```

After it you should update your tests (all actions that returns `promise` should resolve it, I prefer `async ... await` style). Also, your `expect` true is useless, let get rid off it, and add some explicit waiters.

```
describe('Login', () => {
    it('Login Page' async () => {
        await browser.get('http://localhost:9000/apps/admin/');
        const name = element(by.model('ctrl.user.name'));
        await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(name), 10000);
        await name.sendKeys("test1");
        const password = element(by.model('ctrl.user.password'));
        await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password), 10000);
        await password.sendKeys("test1");
        element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

Also, It would be better to find locators using CSS. Update your question with what error this test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is wrapper on selenium, thus when you are plainning to use await/async methods just disable the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER by setting it as false, so that the protractor promises work well with async/await methods.

I also suggest using pagemodel design pattern which will make the code much readable.

```
enter code here


export class loginPageObject{
public emailTextBox: ElementFinder;
public passwordTextBox: ElementFinder;
public signInButton: ElementFinder;
public errorMessage: ElementFinder;

constructor(){      //this.emailTextBox = $("input[type='email']");
    //this.emailTextBox = element(by.css("body > app-root > div > app-login > div > div > form > div > input"));
    this.emailTextBox = $("input[type='email']");
    this.passwordTextBox = $("input[type='password']");
    this.signInButton = $("button[type='submit']");
    this.errorMessage =  $("span");
}
```

}

above is one such sample .. later on you can use it like following way